# how do I form a DSL query to create replica of the same index?

Tags: python, sql, elasticsearch, querydsl

I want to convert this query into DSL to query Elasticsearch. My SQL query is:

```
query = SELECT * FROM log AS log1 AND log2 WHERE
    log1.activity=='A' AND 
    log2.activity=='B' AND 
    log1.timestamp<log2.timestamp AND
    log1.caseid==log2.caseid
```

I am unable to create the instances `log1` and `log2` from the index named `log`.

Can anyone help me in converting this SQL query to DSL? Also, can we query the response of a DSL query from Elasticsearch iteratively? For ex: I want to fire another query over the response of the above query.

Sample document:

`{'type': 'task', 'id': '{7CAA281B-4E33-6644-C657-20AE5BD67D4D}', 'category': 'icm', 'timestamp': '2017-03-03T11:46:07', 'start-time': '2017-03-03T11:45:51', 'end-time': '2017-03-03T11:46:07', 'duration-seconds': 16.0, 'state': 'Complete', 'task-state': 'Complete', 'name': 'Request Invitation Letter_2080', 'task-name': 'Request Invitation Letter_2080', 'type-name': 'Request Invitation Letter', 'task-type-name': 'Request Invitation Letter', 'user-id': 'sam', 'audit-sequence': 1, 'case-folder-id': '{CEC56969-5D4F-7107-911D-DC7990C80420}', 'case-id': '{CEC56969-5D4F-7107-911D-DC7990C80420}', 'source-class-id': '{371ECD7B-27CD-8130-4722-9389571AA876}', 'source-class-display-name': 'Request Invitation Letter', 'task-type-display-name': 'Request Invitation Letter', 'solution-name': 'International Travel', 'case-type-id': '{BDD640FB-0667-1AD1-1C80-317FA3B1799D}', 'case-type-name': 'Travel Reimbursement', 'case-type-display-name': 'Travel Reimbursement', 'case-instance-name': '2080', 'case-instance-id': '{CEC56969-5D4F-7107-911D-DC7990C80420}', 'finished': True, 'health': 'unknown'}`

mappings:

`{'travel-case-simulation-event-summaries': {'aliases': {}, 'mappings': {'icm_event_summary': {'properties': {'audit-sequence': {'type': 'long'}, 'case-folder-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-instance-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-instance-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-state': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-type-display-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-type-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-type-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'case-version': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'category': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'duration-seconds': {'type': 'float'}, 'end-time': {'type': 'date'}, 'finished': {'type': 'boolean'}, 'health': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'icm': {'type': 'object'}, 'id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'solution-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'source-class-display-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'source-class-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'start-time': {'type': 'date'}, 'state': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'task-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'task-state': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'task-type-display-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'task-type-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'timestamp': {'type': 'date'}, 'type': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'type-name': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'user-id': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}}}}, 'settings': {'index': {'creation_date': '1562663151992', 'number_of_shards': '5', 'number_of_replicas': '1', 'uuid': 'Nf-CYDSiT5SL6-oCkKs_TA', 'version': {'created': '6050399'}, 'provided_name': 'travel-case-simulation-event-summaries'}}}}`

Comment: Add some information about the index like its mapping and a sample document

Comment: edited the question to include the mapping and sample

Comment: @PRERNAAGARWAL Its not possible to have self join kind of queries in elastic. The analysis/data you are trying to get from the indexed data is not possible to be achieved with the current schema/mapping of index. You need to re-look at the mapping of index.

Comment: Yes, i thinck i have something similar, i have as a mapping for my document caseId + nested documents list refering to different server, in your case should be something like (activity, timestamp). With all information by caseId in the same document you will be able to make the querry you want to.

Comment: @LeBigCat thanks for the alternative!